# Codeigniter like query showing irrelevant records

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter. I am trying to search records in the database with a like query. I want all the results with the date 02-2023 but it is also showing results with 03-2023 any help

This is my model class.

```
public function get_filter($limit, $start, $newvar) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->like('date', $newvar);
    $query = $this->db->get('mytable');    
    return $query->result_array();
    }

public function filter_count($newvar) {
    $this->db->like('date', $newvar);
    $this->db->from("mytable");
    $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
    return $count;  
    }
```

I have tried with the code given in the above section. Kindly let me know if more details are required. I am expecting to get all the records having the date 02-2023 but the "like" phrase also includes records with 03-2023. I always try to search for the answer before posting it in the forum. But unfortunately, I could not find its solution in previous posts.

I have also noticed that if I manually pass "02-2023" then it works quite fine but not working with $newvar while the value of $newvar is 02-2023 (confirmed).

Answer (score -1):

Case : 1
Try This $newvar date value is something like "2023-03-03".

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($newvar));
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('mytable');
$this->db->where('DATE(date)', $date);
$query = $this->db->get();
$res= $query->result();
```

Case : 2
I assumed that you store date in your database is something like 'Y-m-d H:i:s' .

```
public function get_filter($limit, $start, $newvar) {

    $startDate = $newvar.' 00:00:00';
    $endDate = $newvar.' 23:59:59';

    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->like('date', $newvar);
    $this->db->where('date >=', $startDate);
    $this->db->where('date <=', $endDate);
    $query = $this->db->get('mytable');    
    return $query->result_array();
 }



public function filter_count($newvar) {

    $startDate = $newvar.' 00:00:00';
    $endDate = $newvar.' 23:59:59';    

    $this->db->where('date >=', $startDate);
    $this->db->where('date <=', $endDate);
    $this->db->from("mytable");
    $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
    return $count;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to my query. I think I am unable to convey my problem correctly, some information is missing in my question. Actually this is company's personal application it is using 02-02-2023 for date in mysql database with varchar datatype and $myvar is coming from form select filed like <option value="02-2023">February 2023</option>

Comment: If your date display like 02-02-2023 in database and the datatype is varchar then 
i run this query : select * from mytable where date ilike '%02-2023%';
For me this is not give any wrong date which is ilike 02-03-2023 in my output. 
it only give the records like 02-02-2023, 03-02-2023. I think you are missing something.

Comment: Thank you again for replying to my query. My problem has been solved. Actually there was no problem in my code but problem was in pagination. I was getting $newvar through post like $mymonth = $this->input->POST('themonth'); and problem was that this variable was not working in second page. Now I am doing it like $mymonth = $this->input->GET('themonth', true);  and problem is solved.